# How to make jar file without using any IDE

Tags: java, executable-jar

I decompile jar file using jd-gui app. I made some changes on it.
After that i try to compile main.java file which one include all packages & other java files.
Then it Shows classnotfound exception.
I need to it without using any IDE.
Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doesn't compile anymore. After that i follow that. Before my questions how to bunch of java files like library file , images , other java files etc..

Answer (score 0):

A JAR (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file is a ZIP-compatible archive of your compiled classes and other binary resource.
Feel free to unpack/pack it or treat it the way you treat ZIP-archive, say using your favorite archiving tool, like 7zip.

You can even create a ZIP archive with the contents you wish your JAR to contain and simply change the file extension to **.jar**.

NOTE: in case you use compression for your ZIP-archive, because in that case your manifest often must be the first entry in the archive.